# I Want To Get The Logged In User in my Controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, single-page-application

I am creating a post, now I wanted to get the Authenticated user so I can fill the author_id. But when I use

```php
$request->user(); or Auth::user();
```

It returns null.

How can I pass the data from my vuejs component to Controller?

So here's my Vue Component

**Form.vue**

```
data() {
 return {
  form:{
    title: '',
    seo_title: '',
    excerpt: '',
    body: '',
    image: '',
    meta_description: '',
    meta_keywords: '',
    category_id: '',
    status: '',
    featured: ''
  }
 },
 methods: {
   save() {
     post(this.storeURL, form)
        .then((res) => {
          this.$router.push('Post created successfully')
        })
   }
 }
}
```

**PostController.php**

```php
$filename = $this->getFileName($request->image);
$request->image->move(public_path('storage/posts/'), $filename);

$article = new Post($request->all());

$article->slug = str_slug($request->title, '-');
$article->image = $filename;

$request->user()->posts()->save($article);

return response()
   ->json([
     'saved' => true,
     'id' => $article->id,
     'message' => 'You have successfully posted an article!'
   ]);
```

Comment: Can we see your component and controller along with includes?  Are you using middleware auth, or api, or something different?

Comment: I use Jwt/Token to my authentication. I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ripoche.b/create-a-spa-with-role-based-authentication-with-laravel-and-vue-js-ac4b260b882f)

Comment: for the heck of it can you try auth()->user()

Comment: Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the authenticated user is null, it is most likely that you haven't passed this route through the auth middleware.  In your web.php (or api.php if this is an api route), make sure whatever route you are using is within that middleware.  So, if this is a postCreate route for example, it might look something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('yourPostCreateRoute', 'YourPostController@index');
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. You're right. Now it can get the Auth::user(), but on my admin panel. I also have a middleware ```isAdmin``` ```if (Auth::user()->role === 2)``` when I pass it on the route ```Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'isAdmin:api']]``` it still says Unauthorized.

Comment: Then you have your answer: to get the Auth::user() -- not **null** -- pass the route through the middleware as above to solve the issue in your question.  If you are getting **unauthorized** that is a different question.  The unauth is because you are directly asking if the user has a specific role, right?  So, remove the if check for now, test to see if the route with the middleware works (not null on the user), and then build back with the if check for authorized.

Comment: Thanks man. I solved it. Turns out the helper/api.js that I coded is not getting the correct header that needed to be passed.